# Flattening JSON-file c# - reduce number of foreach-loops

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to deserialize a nested json-file that looks like the following sample:
The output i want is "flat" table. I'm using .net 4.0 and I do not have the option of using third-party librabies like json.net.

```
{
    "responsetime": 33,
    "products": {
        "totalProducts": 25,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bike One",
                "colors": [
                    {
                        "colorId": 44,
                        "name": "green",
                        "chemicals": [
                            {
                                "chemicalId": 99,
                                "chemicalName": "abc"
                            },
                            {
                                "chemicalId": 45,
                                "chemicalName": "bcd"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "colorId": 42,
                        "name": "blue",
                        "chemicals": [
                            {
                                "chemicalId": 96,
                                "chemicalName": "def"
                            },
                            {
                                "chemicalId": 22,
                                "chemicalName": "lkj"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From this I have genereated the following classes:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    public int responsetime { get; set; }
    public Products products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public int totalProducts { get; set; }
    public Product[] products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Color[] colors { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int colorId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Chemical[] chemicals { get; set; }
}

public class Chemical
{
    public int chemicalId { get; set; }
    public string chemicalName { get; set; }
}
```

The output i want is a flat structure like the following:

```
1 Bike One 44 green 99 abc 
1 Bike One 44 green 45 bcd 
1 Bike One 42 blue  96 def 
1 Bike One 42 blue  22 lkj
```

I am able to obtain this with the following code, however this implies 3 foreach-loops which i'm afraid will give bad performance if there are i.e. 100.000 products with N colors and N chemicals each.
Is there any other way to flatten this that will perform better using "vanilla" .net?

```
            String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\example.json"); 
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            ResponseObject rspns = js.Deserialize<ResponseObject>(jsonFileContent);

            foreach (var product in rspns.products.products)
            {
                foreach (var color in product.colors)
                {
                    foreach (var chemical in color.chemicals)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(product.id);
                        Console.WriteLine(product.name);
                        Console.WriteLine(color.colorId);
                        Console.WriteLine(color.name);
                        Console.WriteLine(chemical.chemicalId);
                        Console.WriteLine(chemical.chemicalName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Console.Writeline is bad for performance.   Would you really be outputting 100,000 objects to the Console?

Comment: No this was just to give an example. I would write this to a flat file or a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start having the `ToString` done by the same objects:

```
public class Products
{
    public int totalProducts { get; set; }
    public Product[] products { get; set; }

    public override string ToString(){
        // this iterates all products and stacks their string representation
        var productsStrings = products.Select(x => x.ToString());
        return productsStrings.Aggregate("", (a, n) => a + n + "\n").trimEnd();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Color[] colors { get; set; }

    public override string ToString(){
        // this gets all color strings and prepends the product string
        // "1 Bike" + product (repeated CO times)
        var colorSubstrings = colors.Select(x => x.GetSubstrings());
        var appendOnStrings = colorSubstrings.Select(x => $"{id} {name} {x}");
        return appendOnStrings.Aggregate("", (a, n) => a + n + "\n").trimEnd();
    }
}

public class Color
{
    public int colorId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Chemical[] chemicals { get; set; }

    public string[] GetSubstrings(){
        // this gets all chemicals strings and prepends the color string
        // "44 green" + chemicalString (repeated CH times)
        return chemicals.Aggregate("", (a, chemical) => a + $"{colorId} {name} {chemical.ToString()} \n").trimEnd();
    }
}

public class Chemical
{
    public int chemicalId { get; set; }
    public string chemicalName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString(){
        // this produces a string like -> "99 abc"
        return $"{chemicalId} {chemicalName}";
    }
}
```

Then you just parse the whole chain and call it:

```
String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\example.json");
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

// deserializing JSON to rspns
ResponseObject rspns = js.Deserialize<ResponseObject>(jsonFileContent);

// result will contain the table with all products, colors and chemicals
var result =  rspns.products.ToString();

// printing only once will surely improve the performances
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I'm not able to use third-party librarbies on the production-server as mentioned in the question

Comment: @ImNotARobot I modified the answer to use the libraries you proposed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update - Can you explain what the code is doing? And will this perform better than the foreach-loops?

Comment: Sure @ImNotARobot. I added some comments to make the code clearer. While the computational complexity is the same [`O(pr*co*ch)`], it will perform better than the loop as the output will not be printed for `pr*co*ch` times, but just one at the end. The code is also more easy to maintain now, as you can easily extend the logic. It is not possible to reduce the complexity, as you want to have the three levels printed, this always will translate to `O(pr*co*ch)`.